# How to add delimiters to a csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, pyspark, delimiter

I have a csv file with no delimiters. Is it possible to add delimiters at certain position in PySpark? like,

my file looks like:

```
USDINRFUTCUR23Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12
USDINRFUTCUR24Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12
USDINRFUTCUR25Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12
```

and i want delimiters at 3rd, 6th 12th position

Comment: y dont u run this in python and insert the delimiters there. it seems easier through that path

Comment: do you want pyspark solution, or will pandas solution suffice? in other words, how big is your data

Comment: one file is in GB size and like that i have 84-90 files. So, the file size is huge

Answer (score 3):

For fixed width files there is pandas.read_fwf()

```
widths = [
    3, 
    6, 
    12, 
 ]
df = pd.read_fwf("fixed_width.txt", widths=widths)
df
```

Comment: I tried this, but as the dataset is too long this is taking a lot of time. Is there any pyspark function that does this

Answer (score 2):

For using distributed pyspark solution, there is no similar way to add delimiter right as you read(as there is pandas). A scalable way to solve this would be read the data as is in one column, then use below code (using pyspark functions) to create your columns.

**Creating sample dataframe:**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

list=[['USDINRFUTCUR23Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12'],
      ['USDINRFUTCUR24Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12'],
      ['USDINRFUTCUR25Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12']]

df=spark.createDataFrame(list,['col1'])

df.show(truncate=False)


+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|USDINRFUTCUR23Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
|USDINRFUTCUR24Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
|USDINRFUTCUR25Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Use **substr** and **withcolumn** to create new columns, and drop the first one. You could make a def(function) which reads and performs this code as well, so that you could re use and simplify your pipeline

```
df.withColumn("Currency1", F.col("col1").substr(0,3))\
  .withColumn("Currency2", F.col("col1").substr(4,3))\
  .withColumn("Type", F.col("col1").substr(7,6))\
  .withColumn("Time", F.expr("""substr(col1,13,length(col1))"""))\
  .drop("col1").show(truncate=False)
  #output



+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|Currency1|Currency2|Type  |Time                                                     |
+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|USD      |INR      |FUTCUR|23Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
|USD      |INR      |FUTCUR|24Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
|USD      |INR      |FUTCUR|25Feb201700000000FF00000000000001990067895000000000NNN*12|
+---------+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```